# Rails ActiveRecord includes where with like

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have this Query and I need use like in this query, help me.

scope :filter, -> (query) { includes(:city).where(cities: {name: query}) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string as argument for `where`

```
scope :filter, -> (query) { joins(:city).where('cities.name LIKE ?', "%#{ query }%") }
```

Comment: New code:
scope :filter, -> (query) { includes(:city).where('cities.name LIKE ?', "%#{ query }%") }

When i Use this method return error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "cities"
LINE 1: ...hoods" WHERE (neighborhoods.id NOT IN (170)) AND (cities.nam

Comment: @JhonnyPamponet, updated my answer, replace `includes` with `joins`